# Read folder paths from SQL table and create records for missing parent folders

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, directory

I have a sample table of folder paths like this:

```
Level   Folder
0       C:
1       C:\David
3       C:\David\Documents\Pictures
1       C:\John
2       C:\John\Documents
3       C:\John\Documents\Videos
4       C:\Susan\Documents\Pictures\Photos
```

The "level" represents the folder depth where 0 = root, etc.

I would like to create a record for each parent folder that is missing.  In this case:

```
2       C:\David\Documents
1       C:\Susan
2       C:\Susan\Documents
3       C:\Susan\Documents\Pictures
```

I'm not worried about calculating the Level column, but I have included it in case it makes it easier.  I used this to create my sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE #Folders (
    [Level]     int,
    [Folder]    nvarchar(255)
)

INSERT INTO #Folders
Select 0, 'C:'
UNION
Select 1, 'C:\David'
UNION
SELECT 3,  'C:\David\Documents\Pictures'
UNION
SELECT 1, 'C:\John'
UNION
SELECT 2, 'C:\John\Documents'
UNION
SELECT 3, 'C:\John\Documents\Videos'
UNION
SELECT 4, 'C:\Susan\Documents\Pictures\Photos'

SELECT * FROM #Folders
ORDER BY Folder
DROP TABLE #Folders
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution (and noticed @Forty3 that you just posted one too).  I will check yours out.  Here's what I tried:

```
;WITH CTE ([level], folder, parentfolder) AS (
    -- anchor
    SELECT
        [Level],
        folder,
        LEFT(folder, LEN(folder)-CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(folder)))
    FROM #Folders
    WHERE [Level] > 1
UNION ALL
    SELECT
        [Level]-1,
        parentfolder,
        LEFT(parentfolder, LEN(parentfolder)-CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(parentfolder)))
    FROM CTE
    WHERE [level] > 0
)
INSERT INTO #Folders
SELECT DISTINCT
    [level],
    folder
FROM CTE
WHERE folder NOT IN (SELECT folder from #Folders)
ORDER BY cte.Folder

SELECT * FROM #Folders
```

Which creates the desired output:

```
level   folder
0       S:
1       S:\David
2       S:\David\Documents
3       S:\David\Documents\Pictures
1       S:\John
2       S:\John\Documents
3       S:\John\Documents\Videos
1       S:\Susan
2       S:\Susan\Documents
3       S:\Susan\Documents\Pictures
4       S:\Susan\Documents\Pictures\Photos
```

Comment: `REVERSE` - nice. Overlooked that, and it eliminates the need for my `LastIndexOf` function.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with a user defined function which I so wish T-SQL had:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.LastCharIndex(@searchStr NVARCHAR(10), 
                                  @string NVARCHAR(MAX))
    RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @idx INT = 0
    WHILE CHARINDEX(@searchStr, @string, @idx + 1) > 0
        SET @idx = CHARINDEX(@searchStr, @string, @idx + 1)

    RETURN @idx
END
```

follow it up with a recursive CTE (replacing [table] with your table name):

```
;WITH c ( level, path )
     AS (SELECT o.level,
                o.folder
           FROM [table] o
          WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'f'
                              FROM [table] e
                             WHERE e.folder LIKE o.folder + '\%')
         UNION ALL
         SELECT c.level - 1,
                SUBSTRING(c.path, 1, dbo.LastCharIndex('\', c.path) - 1)
           FROM c
          WHERE dbo.lastcharindex('\', c.path) > 0)
INSERT INTO [table]
SELECT level,
       path
  FROM c
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 'f'
                    FROM [table]
                   WHERE folder = c.path)
```

That should insert into your table all of your missing folders along with their respective levels.

Comment: We were so close if you had used REVERSE.  At first I was expecting comments that this was one of those problems that you can't solve in SQL, and then boom - I wondered about a recursive CTE.  When my CHARINDEX chopped the left side, I looked for REVERSE and I figured it out.  Thanks